# Prevent Linked Static Library from Sharing Shared Library

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries

I have an application that links to a static library and both link against a shared library.  Specifically, the application is a gtest, and the shared library is a class that uses glog.

When I run my test, glog kills the application and prints "You called InitGoogleLogging() twice!" because I did...but it should have been on two different copies of the library, with two different log files.

Is this a linking option, to have shared libraries together or separate?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as asked: kinda, but not really. It is *possible*, but it's convoluted and goes against how dynamic libraries are meant to operate.

As far as fixing your problem goes:

`google::InitGoogleLogging()` is meant called from the top of the `main()` of an application. Making that call from within a class, presumably its constructor, is asking for a bunch of various troubles.

Moving that call to the `main()`, or document the fact that the library requires its users do so will remove the duplicated call and be a cleaner in general.

In a pinch, you can use `IsGoogleLoggingInitialized()` to get out of a jam, but I would personally avoid relying on it if possible, especially in library code.